# Post-order iterator in trees

Tags: java, iterator, binary-search-tree

I am trying to create an `Iterator` implementation for post-order and I am in a slump. I was able to get in-order and pre-order implementations but I can't seem to get a post-order. If you guys can point me in the right direction and give me some tips, that would be amazing.

Here's my in-order class:

```
public class InOrderIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {

    private final Deque<BinaryTreeNode<T>> stack;
    private BinaryTreeNode<T> current;

    public InOrderIterator(BinaryTreeNode<T> root){
        stack = new LinkedList<BinaryTreeNode<T>>();
        this.current = root;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (!stack.isEmpty() || current != null);
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        while (current != null) {
            stack.push(current);
            if (current.hasLeftChild())
                current = current.getLeftChild();
            else
                current = null;
        }

        current = stack.pop();
        BinaryTreeNode<T> node = current;
        if (current.hasRightChild())
            current = current.getRightChild();
        else
            current = null;

        return node.getData();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

Here's a description of pre-, in-, and post-order:

**Pre-order**

1. Visit the root.
2. Traverse the left subtree.
3. Traverse the right subtree.

**In-order**

1. Traverse the left subtree.
2. Visit root.
3. Traverse the right subtree.

**Post-order**

1. Traverse the left subtree.
2. Traverse the right subtree.
3. Visit the root.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Types

Comment: Can you add an explanation of what "post order" is?

Comment: I added a description

Comment: It's not possible to have a `next()` function that is `O(1)`. It will be `O(logn)`. Consider in-order traversal. When you first call the `next()`, it has to traverse from the root to the left-most leaf, so it is O(logn).

Comment: You are so right! How would I go about it not being in 0(1)?

Comment: @user3553265 Exactly the same as the Iterator for TreeSet does. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I googled for a binary tree postorder iterator implementation but could not find a good one. So I implemented mine using two stacks.

```
public class BinaryTreePostorderIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
private TreeNode root;
private Stack<TreeNode> nodes;
private Stack<Boolean> expanded;
public BinaryTreePostorderIterator(TreeNode root) {
    this.root = root;
    nodes = new Stack<>();
    expanded = new Stack<>();
    if (root != null) {
        nodes.push(root);
        expanded.push(false);
    }
}
@Override
public Integer next() {
    if (!hasNext()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("End reached");
    }
    expanded.pop();
    return nodes.pop().val;
}

@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    if (nodes.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    while (!expanded.peek()) {
        expanded.pop();
        expanded.push(true);
        TreeNode node = nodes.peek();
        if (node.right != null) {
            nodes.push(node.right);
            expanded.push(false);
        }
        if (node.left != null) {
            nodes.push(node.left);
            expanded.push(false);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(5);
    root.left = new TreeNode(3);
    root.left.right = new TreeNode(4);
    root.left.left = new TreeNode(2);
    root.right = new TreeNode(7);
    root.right.right = new TreeNode(8);
    root.right.left = new TreeNode(6);

    BinaryTreePostorderIterator pi = new BinaryTreePostorderIterator(root);
    while (pi.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(pi.next());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can't we do it in O(1) space?

Answer (score 0):

One fairly general way to achieve this is by starting from the recursive algorithm, and turning it into an iterative algorithm with an explicit stack. Then, you find points in the recursive algorithm where it would output data, and you pause your computation there (in this example, by returning from the `advance()` method, and making sure the stack is left in a good state for the next call to `advance()`).

My recursive algorithm (I'm using Java 8 and a different `Node` class, but it's along the same lines) was:

```
private void postorder(Node<V> node, Consumer<V> c) {
    // step 0
    if (node == null) {
        return; // pop
    }  
    postorder(node.left, onTraverse); // push
    // step 1
    postorder(node.right, onTraverse); // push
    // step 2
    c.accept(node.data);
    // pop
}
```

which turns into the following iterator:

```
class PostorderIterator<V> implements Iterator<V> {

  class Frame {
      int step;
      Node<V> node;

      public Frame(Node<V> node) {
          this.node = node;
          step = 0;
      }
  }

  Stack<Frame> st = new Stack<>();
  boolean ready;
  V result;

  public PostorderIterator(Node<V> node) {
      st.push(new Frame(node));
  }

  private V advance() {
      while (!st.isEmpty()) {
          Frame f = st.peek();
          switch (f.step) {
              case 0:
                  if (f.node == null) {
                      st.pop(); // return
                  } else {
                      f.step = 1;
                      st.push(new Frame(f.node.left)); // ~postorder(node.left, ...)
                  }
                  break;
              case 1:
                  f.step = 2;
                  st.push(new Frame(f.node.right)); // ~postorder(node.right, ...)
                  break;
              case 2:
                  st.pop(); // ~return
                  return f.node.data;
              default:
                  throw new RuntimeException();
          }
      }
      return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void remove() {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
      if (!ready) {
          result = advance();
          ready = true;
      }
      return result != null;
  }

  @Override
  public V next() {
      if (!ready) {
          result = advance();
          ready = true;
      }
      if (result == null) {
          throw new NoSuchElementException();
      }
      ready = false;
      return result;
  }
}
```

This approach might be a bit clunkier than necessary, but having an explicit `Frame` holding your local variables, arguments, and where you are in the code, should be a decent starting point to a cleaner algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I just played a bit with post order iterator..
This is what I've come up with:

```
    class PostOrderIterator
    implements Iterator<T> {

        private Stack<Node<T>> stack;
        private Node<T> prev;

        public PostOrderIterator() {
            this.stack = new Stack<>();
            recurse(root);
            this.prev = this.stack.peek();
        }

        private void recurse(Node<T> node) {
            if(node == null) {
                return;
            }

            while(node != null) {
                stack.push(node);
                node = node.left;
            }
            recurse(stack.peek().right);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return !stack.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            if(stack.peek().right != this.prev) {
                recurse(stack.peek().right);
            }

            Node<T> next = stack.pop();
            this.prev = next;
            return next.value;
        }
    }
```

Basically, the main idea is that you should think how the initialization process puts the first item to print on the top of the stack, while the rest of the stack follow the nodes that would have been touched by the recursion. The rest would just then become a lot easier to nail.

Also, from design perspective, `PostOrderIterator` is an internal class exposed via some factory method of the tree class as an `Iterator<T>`.